# Compare generated letter with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, compare

My problem is as followed: I want to realise a (really) small application in which I want to generate a letter (between A and E) and compare it with the user input made afterwards. If the user input is not the same as the generated letter a message should pop up, which tells the user that he made the wrong choice. If the user made the right choice, a counter gets +1 and if the user reaches at least 3 of 5 points, he wins a prize. The user has 3 tries before the script ends.

The hurdle is that my main focus lies on php. My knowledge in JavaScript is not that much.

So my script won't do anything when the user types his answer in.

Comment: You're not triggering the function when the input value changes? Try to run the comparation when the user writes or the value in the field changes.

Comment: Move `which = document.getElementById('which').value` inside `compare`

Comment: Also few question `(var i = 0; i < 1; i++)` why? Also `else { if(...){} }`? You can use `else if`. Also in my understanding, correct score should only increment and controlling function should be different

Comment: *still won't work* Can you explain a bit more? Should you stop at wrong character or not?

Comment: I've tried your snippet and I get an error if I use the wrong letter or a success if I use the right one. What is the exact error you are facing?

Comment: That's strange. In jsfiddle it won't throw and error on wrong answer. But if I run the snippet here, it works.

@Rajesh: I want a new generated letter each time one gets answered correctly or false. You got 5 tries and have to reach at least 3 points (1 for each correct answer) to succeed and stop the script

Comment: @montreal I assumed you'd say this. You can check my answer. I have tried to redo your code. Hope it helps you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
The Code beneath is the solution.

```js
String.prototype.last = function(){


return this[this.length - 1]
}
;(function() {
  var score = 0;
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDE";
  var noOfTries = 5;

  function generateCharacter() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % possible.length;
    text = possible[index];
    possible = possible.slice(0, index) + possible.slice(index+1);
    alert(text);
    return text;
  }

  function validate(string) {
    return (string || "").trim().last() === text.last();
  }

  function handleChange(){
   var valid = validate(this.value);
    if(valid){
     score++;
      alert("Richtig!");
    }else{
     alert("Das war leider falsch. Die richtige Antwort wäre " + text + " gewesen!");
    }
    console.log(this.value.length === noOfTries)
    this.value.length === noOfTries ? notify() : generateCharacter();
  }
  
  function notify(){
   if(score == 0) {
     alert("Schade! Sie haben " + score + " Punkte erreicht! Nochmal?");
    }else if(score >= 1 && score <3){
     alert("Schade! Sie haben lediglich " + score + " von 5 Punkten erreicht! Nochmal?");
    }else if(score >= 3 && score <= 5) {
      alert("Herzlichen Glückwunsch! Sie haben " + score + " von 5 Punkten erreicht!");
    }
  }
  
  function registerEvent(){
   document.getElementById('which').addEventListener('keyup', handleChange);
  }
  registerEvent();
  generateCharacter();
})()
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label for="which">Antwort? </label>
    <input type="text" name="which" id="which" placeholder="#" style="width: 9px;">
```

And here's the fiddle: [Compare generated string with user input](https://jsfiddle.net/Labushuya/s2h9zpjj/30/)